# $ \sum_1^\infty (-1)^n \left(1 + \frac{2}{n^2}\right)^{n^2} $ series diverge

Tags: sequences-and-series

$$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n \left(1 + \frac{2}{n^2}\right)^{n^2} $$

I am trying to proove that this series is diverging. Tried cauchy but no  luck as it gives no answer. Tried to apply limit test but cant compare it to anything that helps.

Comment: Have you considered $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac2{n^2}\right)^{n^2}\;?$$

Comment: @BrianM.Scott yes.However according to what I  know we cant tell for sure about Series. (only in case sequence limit is zero

Comment: Just the other way around: if the sequence of terms does *not* have limit $0$, then the series cannot converge. If the series converges, the sequence of terms must tend to $0$.

Comment: In the limit, the series becomes $...e^2-e^2+e^2-e^2...$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT:

Observe that 
$$
\left(1+\frac2{n^2}\right)^{n^2}>1
$$
and remind yourself the necessary condition.

Answer (score 1):

*Hint:* Do you knwo what $\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac2{n^2}\right)^{n^2}$ is? If not, simply use the Bernoulli inequality $(1+x)^n\ge 1+nx$ (for suitable $x,n$).

Comment: I know the limit is $e^2$ But how does this help

Comment: @Yves: It doesn’t matter. If the series converges, the terms must tend to $0$.

Comment: I don’t understand the downvote; this is a fine answer.

Comment: @Yves: Of course it does.

Comment: @Yves: So what? It shows that the terms don’t tend to $0$ in the limit, which in turn shows that the series does not converge.